# MS Access form to get data from multiple (unrelated) tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I know only the basics of Access, so I am having trouble figuring out how to make a form that will access multiple unrelated tables.

I have 5 tables that all contain column named "ID", other coulmns are different for each table. The ID cells are text strings that contain five numbers separated by "-" in form "xx-xxx". A specific ID can be present in 1, 2 or all tables but there is no rule.

I would like to have a lookup form where I would type the specific ID that would get all the values (from the same row) from the tables that contain that ID. Can I achive that with Access 2016?

Comment: Try `Union` query.

Comment: I used query `SELECT Table1.[ID] FROM Table1 UNION SELECT Table2.[ID] FROM Table2 UNION SELECT Table3.[ID] FROM Table3;` So this query represents my record sorce for my form. I am using comobox to input wanted ID however I cannot get Access to output data in subform table using AfterUpdate() event.

Answer (score 0):

So I am getting from your question that your different tables are indeed related to each other through the ID field.

What you need to do is build a query and use this query as the record source for your form. It will look like:

```
SELECT Tbl1.field1, Tbl2.Field2 FROM Tbl1 (INNER/RIGHT/LEFT) JOIN Tbl2 ON Tbl1.ID = Tbl2.ID
```

You can save this query code as an independent query `myQuery` and use is as your form record source.

Comment: All of the tables contain ID field however most of the values are different so `UNION` query is better suited. I still cannot figure out how to use this query as source record and return relevant rows.

Comment: If your query is saved and listed in the query window, you can simply open the form in design mode, and write down the query name in the record source property